# How to Make Vs.net 2010/2012 Custom Tool work in VS.net 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins

I have a custom tool that I inherited that I'm trying to get to work in VS.net 2013. It currently works in Vs.net 2012 but gets the dreaded "Cannot find custom tool on this system" error message.

I was hoping that I would just have to go into the source.extension.vsixmanifest file that is in the code and update it to include  ...

I did this, and lo-and-behold, if you run the generated vsix it prompts for VS.net 2013 and installs nicely into Vs.net 2013 and hows up in the Extensions and Updates tool.

However, most importantly, the custom tool that generates some code-behind for us is not found.

The current tool uses a custom implementation of IVsSinglefileGenerator instead of using the native BaseCodegeneratorWithSite and also implements VSOLE.IObjectWithSite.

It also uses a RegistrationAttribute to register itself. (again, all working in VS.net 2012)

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get this tool to be recognized in vs.net 2013?

Thanks!